# How does Initialization and class inheritance of function work in Swift

Tags: swift, function, initialization, subclass

Based on example from JavaScript code I would like to apply the same steps in Swift. If you can help me to understand how it can work to get area of all shapes.

[image]

Was trying to solve it with below code, however it does not work.

```
class Shape {
    func getArea() {
    }
}

class Square: Shape {
    var a: Double
    init(a: Double) {
        self.a = a
        super.init()
    }
    override func getArea() {
        a * a
    }
}

class Rectangle: Shape {
    var a: Double
    var b: Double
    init(a: Double, b: Double) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        super.init()
    }
    override func getArea() {
        a * b
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    var r: Double
    init(r: Double) {
        self.r = r
        super.init()
    }
    override func getArea() {
        r * r * Double.pi
    }
}

let square = Square(a: 1.1)
let rectangle = Rectangle(a: 5.0, b: 9.1)
let circle = Circle(r: 2.3)
let shapes = [square, rectangle, circle]

func getTotalArea() -> Double {
    
    let areas = shapes.map { $0.getArea() }
    
    let sum = areas.reduce (1, +)
    
    return sum
}

let shapesArea = getTotalArea()
print(shapesArea)
```

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getArea` does not return anything. You have to define `getArea() -> Double`. Also Shape should be a protocol with `func getArea() -> Double` without implementation (without the braces).

Also note that when reducing (summing) areas, you have to start from `0`, not from `1`.

```
protocol Shape {
    func getArea() -> Double
}

class Square: Shape {
    var a: Double
    init(a: Double) {
        self.a = a
    }
    func getArea() -> Double {
        a * a
    }
}

class Rectangle: Shape {
    var a: Double
    var b: Double
    init(a: Double, b: Double) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
    func getArea() -> Double {
        a * b
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    var r: Double
    init(r: Double) {
        self.r = r
    }
    func getArea() -> Double {
        r * r * Double.pi
    }
}

let square = Square(a: 1.1)
let rectangle = Rectangle(a: 5.0, b: 9.1)
let circle = Circle(r: 2.3)
let shapes: [Shape] = [square, rectangle, circle]

func getTotalArea() -> Double {

    let areas = shapes.map { $0.getArea() }

    let sum = areas.reduce(0, +)

    return sum
}

let shapesArea = getTotalArea()
print(shapesArea)
```

A more "Swifty" solution would be tu use structs, using their automatically generated inits, and `area` as a computed property:

```
protocol Shape {
    var area: Double { get }
}

struct Square: Shape {
    var a: Double
    var area: Double {
        a * a
    }
}

struct Rectangle: Shape {
    var a: Double
    var b: Double

    var area: Double {
        a * b
    }
}

struct Circle: Shape {
    var r: Double
    var area: Double {
        r * r * .pi
    }
}

let square = Square(a: 1.1)
let rectangle = Rectangle(a: 5.0, b: 9.1)
let circle = Circle(r: 2.3)
let shapes: [Shape] = [square, rectangle, circle]

func getTotalArea() -> Double {
    return shapes
       .map { $0.area }
       .reduce(0, +)
}

let shapesArea = getTotalArea()
print(shapesArea)
```